# How are the values represented with the "free" command

Tags: linux, memory, swap, ram

I am interested in the totals of the 3 lines. Specifcally, if the "used" values can be counted as what's going on in real time, or if that's just a running total since the OS was started? How does this compare to the vmstat si and so output as opposed to free's representation of swap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Used' is real-time (or at least, close to it). It's important to note that the value for 'used' on the first line includes buffered and cached memory, and that even the value for 'used' on the second line includes file-backed (i.e. non-anonymous) pages that can be dropped without swapping if needed.

Generally, these numbers should (roughly) match what you see in `vmstat`. They both read the basic memory info from `/proc/meminfo`. `vmstat` additionally reads data from `/proc/stat` and `/proc/vmstat`, but its basic memory usage stuff comes from `meminfo`. You can verify this with:

```
strace free 2>&1 | grep open
strace vmstat 2>&1 | grep open
```

Comment: But its still a running total since the last reboot right? In other words, in regards to swap, if any gets used it keeps adding to that number?

Comment: It's not a 'running total' in the sense that it necessarily monotonically increases. The number reported is the number of active pages *currently written* in swap. Even when those pages get paged back in (which happens on page access) they stay in swap, because it would be inefficient to drop them from it; instead, if they remain clean and need to be paged out again, they can be dropped from memory without a write. So swap often monotonically increases in practice. You can always `swapoff`/`swapon` and observe that your swapped page count returns to 0.